# Modifier panel changed

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Cut this short has possible why is there missing options on the bevel,screw.
like had more details in the bevel Mod, but now have 3 bars width type,amount,segments ?

Comment: what do you mean? the modifier bevel? or if you beven in edit mode?

Comment: Modifiers layout has been changed with version 2.90 (I think ?). the same options are there. Some have been renamed or simplified. You just have to click on the foldouts to expand them

Comment: you kknow you had a large window where you have bunch of numbers and details you could use to get the effect you required !

Answer (score -1):

in blender 2.93 alpha:

the bevel modifier e.g. (if you mean this) has lots of options as you can see here (profile + geometry + shading):

[image]

Comment: yeah,Honestly dont understand it !! and the screw mod either !!